# Azure logic apps SFTP Copy File action breaks with some SAS Urls

Tags: azure, sftp, azure-blob-storage, azure-logic-apps

I was experiencing a problem with a logic app which

1. Used the Create SAS URI by path
   action to get a SAS-enabled URL for a blob in a storage account
2. Used the SFTP copy
   file action to copy the file to an SFTP connector

The process would fail roughly 50% of the time with an authorization error when trying to fetch the blob from storage.

```
"actions": {
    "Create_SAS_URI_by_path": {
        "inputs": {
            "body": {
                "Permissions": "Read"
            },
            "host": {
                "connection": {
                    "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azureblob']['connectionId']"
                }
            },
            "method": "post",
            "path": "/datasets/default/CreateSharedLinkByPath",
            "queries": {
                "path": "/container-name/SomeSourceFile.csv"
            }
        },
        "runAfter": {},
        "type": "ApiConnection"
    },    
    "Copy_file": {
        "inputs": {
            "host": {
                "connection": {
                    "name": "@parameters('$connections')['sftp']['connectionId']"
                }
            },
            "method": "post",
            "path": "/datasets/default/copyFile",
            "queries": {
                "destination": "testing-if-works.csv",
                "overwrite": true,
                "source": "@{body('Create_SAS_URI_by_path')?['WebUrl']}"
            }
        },
        "runAfter": {
            "Create_SAS_URI_by_path": [
                "Succeeded"
            ]
        },
        "type": "ApiConnection"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SFTP connector has a bug which causes it to fail if a SAS Url has a plus sign (%2B) in the signature, presumably due to how the connector code handles the URL when it tries to GET the blob by Url. The fix is to double-encode the plus sign:

```
"source": "@{replace(body('Create_SAS_URI_by_path')?['WebUrl'], '%2B', '%252B')}"
```

I'd report this to Microsoft, but can't find the Github repo for the connector. Hope this helps someone else in the future.

Answer (score 2):

This bug has been fixed in SFTP connector. To make it work, please create a new logic app with appropriate actions.

Comment: To be clear - the bug won't be fixed in existing logic apps, only on those where a new SFTP connection is declared? What if an ARM template is published with the same SFTP connection. Will that fix it? What about deleting the SFTP connection and using ARM to recreate?

Comment: SFTP connection can be used the same, however the logic app should be recreated. This is done for backward compatibility purposes, e.g. logic apps with the "workaround" will still work. The newly created logic apps should work without the "workaround" but as is. If you want to use your existing ARM template, please add the following parameter into query parameters for the SFTP action: "queryParametersSingleEncoded": true

Comment: So that your query parameters in your action will look like:

    "queries": {
        "destination": "testing-if-works.csv",
        "overwrite": true,
        "source": "@{body('Create_SAS_URI_by_path')?['WebUrl']}",
        "queryParametersSingleEncoded": true
    }

Comment: For the record, I blew away a logic app and connector and recreated using ARM minus the encoding hack and it still failed. Putting "queryParametersSingleEncoded": true into the code fixed it. Is that because the new default template for an SFTP connection has that pairing by default?